# Character encoding issue when loading a div using jQuery.load()

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, character-encoding

I have one page encoded with utf-8 that is login another page also encoded with utf-8. In order to load one page into a div in the other, I use them load() method of jQuery 1.4.2. Everything works fine in Chrome, but in FireFox all the non-american characters are shown as a strange mark. If I use FireBug to inspect the loaded div, I can see the the inner page (the one thar was loaded) has the encoding charset=iso-8859-1.

What I am missing?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidently fixed the problem. The fact is that all the html files involved in the problem were encoded as UTF-8, all right. However, the main html file was linked to a CSS file that was encoded differently. For some reason, the load() method in jQuery was being influenced by that encoding in FireFox.

I hope this can help other people in similar circumstances.

Bye!

Answer (score 0):

Check the HTTP charset of the inner page: Its web server should serve it as

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Or it might be you have to set it on the script you're requesting through Ajax.

Comment: I checked the inner page and  it´s encoded as utf-8. How do I set it the script?

Comment: How did you check the page? Is it public, so can you provide URLs?

Comment: This is the top of the page that is being loaded:

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<meta content="pt-br" http-equiv="Content-Language" />

<link type="text/css" href="../../css/padrao.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<title>Conhecendo o Fênix</title>
</head>
<body>
 ...

Comment: This doesn't tell you the HTTP response header. Do you load it from a URL? if yes, run 

curl --head http://your.url.whatever/etc/pp